Create CRUD for Blazor using API
In Visual Studio, I can use scaffolded item to add CRUD for an entity using Entity Framework Core. So, I select Razor Component:

Then, I select the template, the model class and the DbContext class:

The generated code uses
@inject IDbContextFactory<HypnoPlatform.Persistence.HypnoContext> DbFactory 

but in the Blazor web application that is not permitted. So, I want to create the CRUD based the API that I can create using the same tool. I can't find an option to do it so. I don't want to change every page manually to replace the code from using the database to using APIs (also because I have 40 tables).

It isn't spelled out in the docs but scaffolding only works for Server-side pages. And only by directly using a DbContext(Factory). So either enable server-side in your project or use another template tool.
Scaffolding is pretty limited, for instance it completely ignores navigation properties. At best it provides a few starter pages, you will have to edit and extend them.
So you can probably work just as quickly by creating a sample folder and then copy/paste that.

Is this enough to add in the page @rendermode InteractiveServer?

It can even work with static rendering, so it depends on how you configured your project.  The scaffolded pages wil not work in the Client project when you included Wasm.
